# HttpClient POST issue

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm accessing the REST web services in Angular 5 by use of `HttpClient` in services. Now in the create (POST) method I need the object that gets created in the database so that I can subscribe to it for extracting some of its details. But for some reason it's giving me null object only. Any help is appreciated.

**service.ts**

```
public create(data: Data): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.post('api/createnode', data);
}
```

**component.ts**

```
object: Data = new Data();
this.object.details = 'testing';
this.dataservice.create(this.object).subscribe((stuff) => {
 console.log(stuff);
});
```

Data contains of ID and DETAILS. ID is auto generated in database and DETAILS is string. The `stuff` that is printed in console is `null`. I wanted the object that just got created in database in there.

Comment: are you returning created object from the backend after creating?

Comment: add options with headers for 'accept' 'application/json'

Comment: What is the signature of your endpoint?

Comment: The endpoint for creating is a SpringBoot service.

   `@PostMapping("/createnode")
    public void create(@RequestBody Data data) {
     repository.save(data);
    }`

Comment: why return type is `void`?

Comment: @Vikas That is the return type for the `save()` method so the return type is set to void. Can you suggest some approach to fetch the created object so that I can return it back to Angular?

Comment: Make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example or post more of your code.

Comment: @Vikas Sorry but plunker and all are blocked through proxy ATM

Comment: Change the back end method so that it returns the object that has been created.

Comment: @ritaj any suggestions on that?

Comment: Post the code of your `repository.save()` method. It should return the created object. Then change your endpoint to `@PostMapping("/createnode") public CREATED_OBJECT_CLASS create(@RequestBody Data data) { return repository.save(data); }`

Comment: Thanks @ritaj that fixed it for me. Stupid me, always stumbling at every steps. Thanks to all for their help

Answer (score 0):

This change at the back end Spring Boot Service fixed it for me

```
@PostMapping("/createnode")
public Data create(@RequestBody Data data) {
 return repository.save(data);
}
```